# How to solve this Laravel session issue

Tags: arrays, laravel, session

I have an array. Then I used php unset method to remove only one index from the array. Then I stored new array in a laravel session.

```
$GetCartItems = json_decode($request->SessionValue);

unset($GetCartItems->items[$request->ArrIndex]);

$request->session()->put('cart', $GetCartItems);
```

After that I retried the array from the laravel session using this below code. Now it's object of type stdClass, not an array. But, I want an array.

```
 $GetCartItems = Session::get('cart');
```

This what I want from laravel session get.

```
App\Cart {#282 ▼
  +items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "item_id" => "29"
      "qty" => array:1 [▶]
      "price" => "1235"
      "size" => array:1 [▶]
      "item" => App\Product {#283 ▶}
      "produ" => array:1 [▶]
    ]
    1 => array:6 [▶]
    2 => array:6 [▶]
  ]
  +totalQty: 3
  +totalPrice: 3705
  +count: 3
  +ArrCount: 3
}
```

This is what I get after remove one index with elements and stored in a laravel session.

```
{#282 ▼
  +"items": array:3 [▼
    0 => {#283 ▼
      +"item_id": "29"
      +"qty": array:1 [▶]
      +"price": "1235"
      +"size": array:1 [▶]
      +"item": {#284 ▶}
      +"produ": array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => {#286 ▶}
    2 => {#290 ▶}
  ]
  +"totalQty": 6
  +"totalPrice": 7410
  +"count": 6
  +"ArrCount": 3
}
```

How can I get rid of this object of type stdClass and get what I want ??

Comment: I think you have serialized App\Cart Model and nested *items* relation? Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

In the following line you are converting the SessionValue into an stdClass Object, because json_decode converts a serialized object into an stdClass

```
$GetCartItems = json_decode($request->SessionValue);
```

If you add a true in the second's json_decode param you will get an Array instead of an stdClass

```
$GetCartItems = json_decode($request->SessionValue, true);
```

In the other hand, there is no easy way to get a Cart Instance with json_encode but you can try to use Object Serialization https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php

```
<?php

class Cart implements \Serializable
{
    public $items;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = [
            1,2,3
        ];
    }
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize($this->items);
    }
    public function unserialize($items) {
        $this->items = unserialize($items);
    }
}
```

This way you will be able to serialize your object and persist it into the session

```
<?php

$GetCartItems = unserialize($request->SessionValue);

unset($GetCartItems->items[$request->ArrIndex]);

$request->session()->put('cart', serialize(($GetCartItems));
```

Next time when you try to do this

```
$GetCartItems = unserialize($request->SessionValue);
```

You will get a Cart Instance with the right values :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to convert the object to an array, you can use the `toArray()` method, like so:

```
$GetCartItems = Session::get('cart')->toArray();
```